# How do Eclipse plugins work?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, plugin.xml

Specifically, I would like to know exactly what happens when Eclipse loads a plugin.

To explain what I'm looking for: 
I am currently trying to decipher a plugin that reformats Java code to make nicer comparisons (found [HERE](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2007/08/23/updating-the-java-compare-plugin/)).

The main class that gets things going is apparently the class `JavaContentViewerCreator` which implements `IViewerCreator`. I came to this conclusion because it's the only class mentioned in the `plugin.xml` file.

`JavaContentViewerCreator` requires two parameters for the one method it has; a `Composite` object, and a `CompareConfiguration` object. What is passing `JavaContentViewerCreator` these parameters? Where is being called from?

Mainly, what is calling `JavaContentViewerCreator` and what triggers this plugin to execute all the other classes?

I'd like to know generally how plugins get started (where's the starting point) and how to trace the rest of it from there.

All answers, other than "read a book" ([which I am](http://goo.gl/Q8B1O)), will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "how to trace" is one of the main problems in the world of SWT/RCP... The design doesn't make this easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Lookup extension point ID in that plugin. In your plugin.xml there will be element like `<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">` - "com.eclipse.ui.commands" is the extension point id.
2. Lookup that ID in Eclipse documentation - [Platform](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/index.html?cp=2_1_1) or [Java Development Tools](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/index.html?cp=3_1_1). If the ID is not in either document - post it in comment here.

Comment: Thanks for the direction... there are two `<extension>` tags whose `point` attributes are: `org.eclipse.ui.theme` and  `org.eclipse.compare.contentMergeViewers` respectively.

Comment: Now you can read help to find out what they are about ;) They both come from Platform.